# What are "feeder cells"?

Tags: cell-biology

What exactly are "feeder cells"? A paper I'm reading says they harvested the cells and then plated them onto feeder cells. What is the purpose? Is in order to promote growth?

Answer (score 2):

> Cultures of growth-arrested feeder cells have been used for years to promote cell proliferation, particularly with low-density inocula. Basically, feeder cells consist in a layer of cells unable to divide, which provides extracellular secretions to help another cell to proliferate.

From this paper's abstract: 
[Feeder Layer Cell Actions and Applications](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4533020/)